# Show values on selected area (JavaScript chart)

Tags: javascript, charts

I am looking for a JavaScript library that allows to select an area in the chart and show its values (not zooming) retrieved from MySQL.

Example: show the student id in the chart

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the team here at [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) and I'm happy to help you out. I used ZingChart for this answer, and I highly recommend that you check it out. The branded version is completely free to use, and includes all of the same great features and chart types as our paid version.

Getting started, I first created a MySQL table on my local machine, and filled it with the following data:

[image: Student roster]

Then I created JavaScript variables in my page to keep a running tally of the number of students who received a certain grade. These are used in the chart JSON to plot each point along the x scale.

```
var APluses=0,
    As=0,
    BPluses=0,
    Bs=0,
    CPluses=0,
    Cs=0,
    DPluses=0,
    Ds=0,
    Fs=0;
```

I opened a connection to my roster database, and pulled in all of the student data into an array of arrays.

```
<?php
//Open a connection to my database 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "roster");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>

var students=[<?php 
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM records");
while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    echo '["'.$info['ID'].'","'.$info['Grade'].'"],'; //var students=[["ID0","Grade0"],["ID1","Grade1"],...,["IDn","Graden"]]
    echo '[]'; //Add empty element after final concatenation
?>];
students.pop(); //Pop off final, empty element so that we don't have a trailing comma
```

Next, I set up a switch statement that uses each student's grade as the expressions for the switch, with each case concatenating the student's ID to the corresponding element in the studentIds array of strings, which I use in labels later on, and incrementing our letter grade counters.

```
var studentIds=["Students with A+'s:<br>","Students with A's:<br>","Students with B+'s:<br>","Students with B's:<br>","Students with C+'s:<br>","Students with C's:<br>","Students with D+'s:<br>","Students with D's:<br>","Students with F's:<br>"];
for(var n=0;n<students.length;n++){
    switch(students[n][3]){
        case "A+":
        studentIds[0]=studentIds[0].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        APluses++;
        break;
        case "A":
        studentIds[1]=studentIds[1].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        As++;
        break;
        case "B+":
        studentIds[2]=studentIds[2].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        BPluses++;
        break;
        case "B":
        studentIds[3]=studentIds[3].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        Bs++;
        break;
        case "C+":
        studentIds[4]=studentIds[4].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        CPluses++;
        break;
        case "C":
        studentIds[5]=studentIds[5].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        Cs++;
        break; 
        case "D+":
        studentIds[6]=studentIds[6].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        DPluses++;
        break;
        case "D":
        studentIds[7]=studentIds[7].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        Ds++;
        break;
        case "F":
        studentIds[8]=studentIds[8].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
        Fs++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, I created the chart. Creating a chart involves 3 main steps. Including the scripts, creating a chart div element with a unique id, and calling the zingchart.render method.

In my page, I included the ZingChart scripts that come in the [download package](http://www.zingchart.com/try/):

```
<script src="lib/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>
```

I placed a div with a unique ID in the page (this will be where the chart is rendered):

```
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

I called the zingchart.render method:

```
window.onload=function(){
    zingchart.render({
        id:"myChart",
        width:"50%",
        height:400,
        data:{
            "type":"area",
            "title":{
                "text":"Overall Class Grades"
            },
            "plot":{
                "tooltip":{
                    "visible":0
                }
            },
            "scale-x":{
                "values":["A+","A","B+","B","C+","C","D+","D","F"],
                "offset-start":10,
                "offset-end":10
            },
            "scale-y":{
                "values":"0:5:1"
            },
            "series":[
            {
                "values":[["A+",APluses],["A",As],["B+",BPluses],["B",Bs],["C+",CPluses],["C",Cs],["D+",DPluses],["D",Ds],["F",Fs]]
            }
            ]
        }
    });
```

Since you want the IDs to appear when you click on each node, I used the ZingChart API to create a node_click event listener, which adds a label object attached to the clicked node and uses the corresponding element from our studentIds to display the list of IDs.

```
zingchart.node_click = function(p) {
      console.log(p);
      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'removeobject', {
        type: 'label',
        class: 'labelClass'
    });
      if (p.nodeindex == 0) {
        zingchart.exec('myChart', 'addobject', {
          'type': 'label',
          'data': {
            'id': 'label1',
            'class': 'labelClass',
            'text': studentIds[p.nodeindex],
            'hook': "node:index=" + p.nodeindex,
            'offset-y': -50,
            "offset-x": 30,
            "background-color": "white",
            "border-radius": 5,
            "shadow": 0,
            "z-index": 10,
            "border-width": 1,
            "border-color": "black"
        }
    });
    } else {
        zingchart.exec('myChart', 'addobject', {
          'type': 'label',
          'data': {
            'id': 'label1',
            'class': 'labelClass',
            'text': studentIds[p.nodeindex],
            'hook': "node:index=" + p.nodeindex,
            'offset-y': -50,
            "background-color": "white",
            "border-radius": 5,
            "shadow": 0,
            "z-index": 10,
            "border-width": 1,
            "border-color": "black"
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I'll include a snippet, sans PHP, for you to play with.

```js
var APluses=0,
    As=0,
    BPluses=0,
    Bs=0,
    CPluses=0,
    Cs=0,
    DPluses=0,
    Ds=0,
    Fs=0;
    var students=[["162835","D+"],["725383","B+"],["678942","A"],["678923","A+"],["927345","A+"],["534902","B"],["634283","C"],["927365","B+"],["917254","A"],["152848","C+"],["624184","D"],[]];
    
    students.pop();
    var studentIds=["Students with A+'s:<br>","Students with A's:<br>","Students with B+'s:<br>","Students with B's:<br>","Students with C+'s:<br>","Students with C's:<br>","Students with D+'s:<br>","Students with D's:<br>","Students with F's:<br>"];
    for(var n=0;n<students.length;n++){
        switch(students[n][1]){
            case "A+":
            studentIds[0]=studentIds[0].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            APluses++;
            break;
            case "A":
            studentIds[1]=studentIds[1].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            As++;
            break;
            case "B+":
            studentIds[2]=studentIds[2].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            BPluses++;
            break;
            case "B":
            studentIds[3]=studentIds[3].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            Bs++;
            break;
            case "C+":
            studentIds[4]=studentIds[4].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            CPluses++;
            break;
            case "C":
            studentIds[5]=studentIds[5].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            Cs++;
            break; 
            case "D+":
            studentIds[6]=studentIds[6].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            DPluses++;
            break;
            case "D":
            studentIds[7]=studentIds[7].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            Ds++;
            break;
            case "F":
            studentIds[8]=studentIds[8].concat(students[n][0]+"<br>");
            Fs++;
            break;
        }
    }

zingchart.node_click = function(p) {
    console.log(p);
      zingchart.exec('myChart', 'removeobject', {
        type: 'label',
        class: 'labelClass'
    });
      if (p.nodeindex == 0) {
        zingchart.exec('myChart', 'addobject', {
          'type': 'label',
          'data': {
            'id': 'label1',
            'class': 'labelClass',
            'text': studentIds[p.nodeindex],
            'hook': "node:index=" + p.nodeindex,
            'offset-y': -50,
            "offset-x": 50,
            "background-color": "white",
            "border-radius": 5,
            "shadow": 0,
            "z-index": 10,
            "border-width": 1,
            "border-color": "black"
        }
    });
    } else {
        zingchart.exec('myChart', 'addobject', {
          'type': 'label',
          'data': {
            'id': 'label1',
            'class': 'labelClass',
            'text': studentIds[p.nodeindex],
            'hook': "node:index=" + p.nodeindex,
            'offset-y': -50,
            "background-color": "white",
            "border-radius": 5,
            "shadow": 0,
            "z-index": 10,
            "border-width": 1,
            "border-color": "black"
        }
    });
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    zingchart.render({
        id:"myChart",
        width:"100%",
        height:400,
        data:{
            "type":"area",
            "title":{
                "text":"Overall Class Grades"
            },
            "plot":{
                "tooltip":{
                    "visible":0,
                    "text":"%data-id"
                },
                "selection-mode":"plot",
                "selected-state":{
                    "background-color":"red"
                }
            },
            "scale-x":{
                "values":["A+","A","B+","B","C+","C","D+","D","F"],
                "offset-start":10,
                "offset-end":10

            },
            "scale-y":{
                "values":"0:5:1"
            },
            "series":[
            {
                "values":[["A+",APluses],["A",As],["B+",BPluses],["B",Bs],["C+",CPluses],["C",Cs],["D+",DPluses],["D",Ds],["F",Fs]]
            }
            ]
        }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://zingchart.com/playground/lib/zingchart/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

---